# Cannot access Heroku postgres from CLI, SSL support issue

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I'm having trouble connecting to my Postgres database on Heroku.
I run `heroku pg:psql` from the terminal, and get the error:

```
psql: sslmode value "require" invalid when SSL support is not compiled in
```

All the instances I find of this error online are php related, and it's only started acting up recently. Anybody know what's up with this?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading or reinstalling the tool belt?

Comment: Upgrading the toolbelt will not help

Answer (score 1):

Your local psql binary was not compiled with SSL support. You will need to locally recompile (or otherwise acquire for your os a binary of) postgres with SSL.

Comment: OK. Any idea how to do this with Homebrew on OS X?